# Argument passed to controller is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've been working on a relatively simple application in ASP.NET Core that displays the status of various nodes in a network. It displays their latest status, and some other information.

For this, I've made a controller which has an action that takes a node's name, performs a lookup in the node manager, and returns the detail view for that specific node. This controller action is implemented like so:

```
public IActionResult Detail(string name)
{
    // Maybe redirect this to the node detail overview once it's done?
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return View("PageNotFound");

    var viewModel =
        Current.NodeManager.Statuses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Node.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (viewModel == null)
        return View("PageNotFound");

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I'm linking to this action from my overview page. The HTML I'm using to do this is:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Node" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@status.Node.Name">@status.Node.DisplayName</a>
```

For one of my nodes, this produces the following link:

`http://example.com/Node/Detail/Temeria`

And from what I understand from the ASP.NET Core documentation, the controller should capture "Temeria" here as the argument for the `Detail` action of `NodeController`, but it reliably refuses to do so. `name` here is always null.

I've also messed around with the routing in `Startup.Configure`, by adding the following route to the controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Node Detail",
    template: "{controller=Node}/{action=Detail}/{name}");
```

But unfortunately, to no avail. Every time I invoke the action, be it via clicking the link I've outlined above, or visiting the detail action manually by typing in the URL in my browser, ASP.NET Core spits out the following log line:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method Aegis.Controllers.NodeController.Detail (Aegis) with arguments () - ModelState is Valid

I'm at a loss here - am I missing something really obvious here, or does ASP.NET Core not work with primitive types and should I resort to the "model binding" I've been seeing in the guides (which seems to be a bit overkill for an action as simple as this one)?

I've seen various other questions similar to this one, but none of them were for ASP.NET Core. I've done similar projects in classic ASP.NET, and never had this issue with that framework.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in this line:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Node" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@status.Node.Name">@status.Node.DisplayName</a>
```

I've changed `asp-route-id` to `asp-route-name` and everything works fine. So the answer is:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Node" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-name="@status.Node.Name">@status.Node.DisplayName</a>
```

Comment: Legend - that did the trick! I obtained the `asp-route-id` from one of the tutorials in the documentation, but never realised that it matched their id parameter until you've pointed this out just now. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yeah, it is very common mistake, you always need to check whether parameter name in action and `asp-route` or `name` in form controls. My pleasure to answer this question!